# Forcing all derived classes to implement a certain property with readonly nature

Tags: c#, windows

Just trying to learn what is the best way to do it, I will try to explain my problem, it may seem a longer question, sorry for that,

I have a class Element, two classes Shape and Audio derives from it, further two classes Text and Image derive from Shape, and further class Video derive from Image. I need to implement a type property on each of these classes which must have a read-only nature as there is no sense of setting a type on any of these classes other than the actual type, for ex : a Type property on Image will always return a value Image and nothing else. So how do I implement this hierarchy which forces all classes to implement Type property? Each of these classes have their own functionalities other than base Element class which can be marked abstract, which will allow me to mark Type property as abstract which will force it to be implemented on derived class but only at one level, how do I enforce it be implemented on Video as well?
Please suggest me the best approach on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try a generic interface?

Comment: What does this property for? I'm not sure but look at the Visitor pattern. Maybe it's what you need.

Comment: Wait, why would you have classes implement this? Why not just use the .NET methods for getting the type?

Comment: @BobHorn : Thanks Bob for replying, I am not an expert on generic interfaces, but as far as I understand your suggestion, I can put common behavior in an interface, but to get it working, I doubt I will have to implement it on each and every class in my hierarchy? If I am right then will it not be duplication of code?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy : Thanks for showing interest, I have never used visitor pattern but after doing a quick google search, I found that visitor pattern is used when we want to perform similar operations have to be performed on objects of different types grouped in a structure. By the way, Thanks a lot that was a new thing to learn for me.

Comment: @BobHorn : About your other comment, I will need to compare the type of my objects a lot, I doubt that will be easy or at least logical to do with .NET methods like GetType(), If I am getting you correct?

Comment: @VibhoreTanwer Why wouldn't it be easy or logical? All .NET types have the GetType() method, so your issue is solved. Why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface which defines the Type property, make all classes that need to be forced to implement Type, inherit from this interface.

Comment: Thanks Justin, for looking, By using this approach, I think i will have to repeat code in every class? Or if you are suggesting that I create this interface with only those properties that are to be defined in every class? That seems like a solution. Please correct me on this.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting the latter, so that the interface basically states what needs to be conformed to for any object that wants to expose the 'Type' (and possibly other) properties.

Answer (score 0):

As you state, the base class can make a property abstract which will force it to be implemented by all derived classes.  However, if your second tier of classes (Text and Image) are concrete, you cannot force derived classes (Video) to implement a method (since the concrete class must, by definition, be fully implemented).

You can easily mark the property as Virtual in the Text/Image classes so that it *can* be overridden by a derived class, but this won't force it.

Perhaps you could do something with generics, and a generic base class or interface, but that would depend on more knowledge of your design.

You may want to re-consider how you've designed the object hierarchy (if possible) - Perhaps Video should not derive from Image.  Is it really an "is a" relationship?  If not, perhaps you could either change the object hierarchy or use Interfaces rather than base classes to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Brian, Please forgive me but I don't understand how a generic interface or something will help? Can you please explain a bit? As far as hierarchy is concerned, Image is like a single frame and Video is just a collection of frame so Image contains a whole lot of functionality that is available for Video as well.

Comment: I would need to see the code to better understand if there's a way to use a generic base class or an interface to solve your problem.  These are different approaches for working around limitations of inheritance (or for cases when inheritance isn't the right approach).  But if Video is a collection of Images, it sounds like you're talking about [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), not inheritance.  I would suggest looking up Composition and seeing if that's a better approach.